# How can I extract a table from many Excel documents to Pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have hundreds of similar Excel files, but containing descriptions and other informations too. (see [Excel Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/765Lx.jpg)) I would like to extract the tables or their data only for further works. I managed an iterative way to but it is inaccurate, and error prone to even a cell of difference, and in some cases there are differences. So is there any way to process this some dynamic way, or manual labour?

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import os

path = r'/Users/.../datafolder'[enter image description here][1]


all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xlsx"))

#define empty lists to store the values

East_England = []
London = []
Midlands = []
North_East = []
North_West = []
South_East = []
South_West = []

for f in all_files:
    
    # read the csv file
    df = pd.read_excel(f)

    # read and append the specific cells to a list
    East_England.append(df.iloc[14,3])
    London.append(df.iloc[15,3])
    Midlands.append(df.iloc[16,3])
    North_East.append(df.iloc[17,3])
    North_West.append(df.iloc[18,3])
    South_East.append(df.iloc[19,3])
    South_West.append(df.iloc[20,3])
display(East_England)   
display(Midlands)
display(North_East)
display(North_West)
display(South_East)
display(South_West)
```

Comment: Have a look at `https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/developers-guide/main-api`. Much easier once you figure it out, and data seems corrected/updated (there's a slight mismatch with your sample file). E.g. try: `import requests`, `import pandas as pd`, and then `url = 'https://api.coronavirus.data.gov.uk/v1/data?filters=areaType=region&structure={"date":"date","name":"areaName","first":"cumPeopleVaccinatedFirstDoseByVaccinationDate"}'` and: `df = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url).json()['data'])`. Repeat for "Second" (it's apparently fairly heavy, the API doesn't like it together at once).

Comment: So, then try `df[df.date == '2021-09-01']` and you'll get pretty much the same data, but updated, as mentioned, and with a slightly different cut for the regions. E.g. in your sample it's `North East and Yorkshire`, through the API, you'll get `North East` and `Yorkshire and The Humber` separately. But you can sum those of course.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this, and see how it goes!

Comment: Didn't even had to playing around with the API, the following link has download facility, in which I can configure what I need exactly! So basically a better data source was the solution! https://coronavirus.data.gov.uk/details/download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the common denominator is that the tables you want to extract have border styles. So you could open the file with `openpyxl` first, and filter out the cells that have border styles, then pass it to pandas.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd
import requests
from io import BytesIO

url = 'https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2021/05/COVID-19-daily-announced-vaccinations-09-May-2021.xlsx'
r = requests.get(url)

wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(r.content))
ws = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]] # select first sheet

#iterate cells, set value of cells with no left border to None
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if not cell.border.left.style:
            try:
                cell.value = None
            except:
                continue

df = pd.DataFrame(ws.values).dropna(how='all', axis=0).dropna(how='all', axis=1).reset_index(drop=True) # load into pandas, drop empty rows and columns
df = df.T.set_index(0).T # set first row as header
```

Output:

|  | NHS Region of Residence | 1st dose | 2nd dose | Cumulative Total Doses to Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Total | 29578216 | 14871208 | 44449424 |
| 2 | East of England | 3541361 | 1773421 | 5314782 |
| 3 | London | 3734565 | 1769567 | 5504132 |
| 4 | Midlands | 5657588 | 2798749 | 8456337 |
| 5 | North East and Yorkshire | 4659848 | 2396705 | 7056553 |
| 6 | North West | 3744975 | 1975801 | 5720776 |
| 7 | South East | 4837856 | 2412643 | 7250499 |
| 8 | South West | 3209877 | 1699091 | 4908968 |

Comment: I accept this as an answer, because solved another similar problem of mine. For my particular problem it was easier to go with the commented solution, that is gathering the data through API.